# How to refresh pivot table on another sheet without making it the active sheet

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, scrollbar

I am using scroll bars connected to a pivot table. I extract data from my pivot using 'GETPIVOTDATA'.

I am using scroll bars to make percentage changes to the values so i need to refresh the pivot table. My scroll bars are on a separate sheet and my pivot table is on a seperate sheet. This is the code I am using, but everytime i make a scrollbar change, it goes to the other sheet and comes back, how do i get it to do it in the background?

```
'Sub ScrollBar2_Change()
'
' ScrollBar2_Change Macro
'

'
Sheets("whatif pivot2").Select
Range("E29").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
Sheets("Whatif").Select
Range("C27").Select
End Sub`
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sheets("whatif pivot2").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh
```

If that doesn't work try .RefreshTable instead.

Comment: Thank you so much!!